# Node push notification repeatly ask for password

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I am using [node-apn](http://node-apn) to send push notification to Apple devices, and I've made it a standalone server so that it receives message from the outside source.

However when the server start it doesn't ask for password. It asks for password when the first message from the outside source comes in. Sometimes it seems to ask more than once.

Is there a way to make it ask for password just once and all for good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I realize that you can put the PEM passphrase as an option.
I don't know about the security implications of this, however. I think it's better to load it from some environmental variable.

```
var options = {
  passphrase: 'XXXXX'
};

var apnConnection = new apn.Connection(options);
```